# Find the middle value in array that meets condition

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, find, logic

I've got logical array(zeros and ones) 1500x700

I want to find "1" in every column and when there are more than one "1" in column i should choose the middle one.

Is that possible to do it? I know how to find "1", but don't know how to extract the middle "1" if there's couple of "1" in one column.

Answer (score 1):

The `find` function returns the indices of your ones.

```
>> example=[1,0,0,1,0,1,1];
>> indices=find(example)

indices =

     1     4     6     7

>> indices(floor(numel(indices)/2))

ans =

     4
```

Do this for each column and you have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can

1. Get the row and column indices of ones with [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html);
2. Apply [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) with a custom function to get the middle row index for each column.

```
x = [1 0 0 0 0; 0 0 1 0 0; 1 0 1 0 0; 1 0 0 1 0];                      % example
[ii, jj] = find(x);                                                    % step 1
result = accumarray(jj, ii, [size(x,2) 1], @(x) x(ceil(end/2)), NaN);  % step 2
```

Note that:

- For an even number of ones this gives the *first* of the two middle indices. If you prefer the *average* of the two middle indices replace `@(x) x(ceil(end/2))` by `@median`.
- For a column *without ones* this gives `NaN` as result. If you prefer a different value, replace the input fifth argument of `accumarray` by that.

Example:

```
x =
     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0
     1     0     1     0     0
     1     0     0     1     0

result =
     3
   NaN
     2
     4
   NaN
```